Siemens Star Target with black ring - What's causing it?
I am designing an imaging system with should create an image from focal plane to focal plane (in contrast to infinity to focal plane).
The system features a lens with tunable focal length.
Starting from the object, the setup consists of a set of normal, aspheric lenses, after some distance the tunable lens and then the camera.
For illumination I use a bicycle lamp with a band-pass filter (FWHM 10nm). Therefore, I assume that I have incoherent light and I can neglect any interference.
When the tunable lens acts as just a glass plate, I get this very nice result using a Siemens star target:

No spurious resolution. No dark ring around the bright center. I confirmed, that this is how the image should look like.
By changing the focal length of the tunable lens, I should be able to change the focal plane of the object -- I confirmed this in Zemax.
Even by really fine tuning the position of the star target (I have a linear stage with µm resolution) I can not achieve better results than this:

I can still see the bright center, but there is a dark ring around this. The ring is dark, meaning that it is not just blurred out. Then the ring would look more grey-ish.
Then I see some behavior of the stripes which can be attributed to spurious resolution.
However, spurious resolution is created by defocus, which should not be present here.
Any ideas how this effect can be explained? Especially the dark ring around the bright ring.

I googled for "tunable focal length," and there seems to be more than one technology in the works that fits that description. Not that I would be able to answer questions about its limitations, but maybe somebody could help if they knew which tunable focal length technology you are using.

@SolomonSlow: I don't think that the specific tunable lens would matter too much, but it is the ML-20-37 (https://www.optotune.com/ml-20-37-lens) from Optotune

So, basically, a transparent, elastic balloon filled with transparent fluid, and the curvature of the surface is adjusted by changing the fluid pressure. Again, I am not an expert, and I won't try to answer, but it seems as if there could be some significant practical limitations to the precision with which the shape of the refracting surface can be controlled.
